# angularjs repeat table rows inside rows

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've read a few existing threads on this topic and I think I'm close but I may need a bit of help. I'm trying to display line items for purchase orders. If the row in line items array has inventId=0 I want to display all the information about it as a single row. If, however, inventId > 0 then I want to display itemId, nickname and description in the "header" row and the rest of the columns as a normal row similar to the tracking row. Here is my current code that ends up with the "header" row repeated above each "matrix" row.

```html
<table id="lineItemsTable"
       class="table table-bordered table-hover table-list scTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Labels.itemId</th>
            <th>@Labels.nickname</th>
            <th>@Labels.description</th>
            <th>@Labels.ordered</th>
            <th>@Labels.cost</th>
            <th>@Labels.extension</th>
            <th>@Labels.price</th>
            <th>@Labels.margin</th>
            <th>@Labels.receiveLocation</th>
            <th>@Labels.received</th>
            <th>@Labels.remaining</th>
            <th>@Labels.vendorPartNo</th>
            <th>@Labels.upc</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat-start="result in crud.model.lineItems track by $index"
            ng-click="crud.selectedIndex=$index;"
            ng-class="{selected: $index === crud.selectedIndex}">
            <td>{{result.itemId}}</td>
            <td>{{result.item}}</td>
            <td>{{result.itemDescrip}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="result.inventId!==0">
            <td></td><td></td><td>{{result.inventoryDescrip}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm attaching a screen shot of what I want to achieve using an array of lineItems:

[image]

Comment: My array is sorted by ItemId, InventId. So, when I am inside the same ItemId I need to only have the top portion once. How can I avoid repeating the header rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always helps to put my question in writing. As soon as I posted it, I think I figured out a solution. I'll add rowNumber column into the stored procedure returning line items and will display that info only when Rn = 1.

I made it work although I could not make the original odd/even rows backcolor. Now all "header" rows look like even, which is probably an OK effect.