# ng-repeat and selected row

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

This is a continuation of the previous question [angularjs repeat table rows inside rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51488037/angularjs-repeat-table-rows-inside-rows)

I'm unable to figure out if there is a solution for the following problem. I want to be able to highlight current row when I click on it (and do it independently for description and "child" rows but in the actual rows array I don't have them separately - I just repeat the first row twice using ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end approach).

I currently have the following code:

```html
<tr ng-repeat-start="result in crud.model.lineItems track by $index"
                            ng-click="crud.selectedIndex=$index;"
                            ng-class="{selected: $index === crud.selectedIndex && result.rowNumber===1}">
                            <td ng-if="result.rowNumber===1">
                                <a href="{{'Items/DCI#/edit/item/'+ result.departmentId + '/' + result.categoryId + '/' + result.itemId}}" 
                                   target="_blank"
                                   title="@Labels.editItemInNewTab">{{result.itemId}}</a>
                            </td>
                            <td ng-if="result.rowNumber===1">{{result.item}}</td>
```

several more td to follow.

Then I have the following:

```html
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="result.inventId!==0"
                            ng-click="crud.selectedIndex=$index;"
                            ng-class="{selected: $index === crud.selectedIndex && result.rowNumber > 1}">
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>
                                {{result.inventoryDescrip}}
                            </td>
```

I'm trying to achieve the following: if click on the top (description) row, I want to highlight it. If I click on each of the next rows I want to highlight each of them independently too (and make the top description row not highlighted).

I can not seem to figure out if there is some condition to not make top 2 (description + my first matrix) rows to not be highlighted together.

With my current approach I can highlight the top description row and all rows except for the first one. I tried various things, but I don't see a way to get it highlighted the way I need.

Do you see my problem and possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work!

Here is my solution:

```html
<tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat-start="result in crud.model.lineItems track by $index"
                            ng-click="crud.selectedMatrixIndex=-1;crud.selectedIndex=$index;"
                            ng-class="{selected: $index === crud.selectedIndex}">
```

at the top of the ng-repeat and

```html
 <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="result.inventId!==0"
                            ng-click="crud.selectedMatrixIndex=$index;crud.selectedIndex = -1;"
                            ng-class="{selected: $index === crud.selectedMatrixIndex}">
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>
                                {{result.inventoryDescrip}}
                            </td>
```

at the bottom. I initialize the MatrixIndex with -1 in the controller and the selectedIndex with 0. As a result I am now able to select my rows independently (top description row and "child" rows).